# Listar chamadas com ou sem idFuncionario preenchido

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Senhores.
Tenho a seguinte função.

```
    $sql = "
            SELECT 
                c.*,
                cli.*,
                cli.razaosocial as nomeCliente,
                c.idCliente as idClienteChamada
            FROM 
                chamada as c, 
                cliente as cli 
            WHERE 
                c.idChamada = '".$id."' 
            AND 
                cli.idCliente = c.idCliente
    ";
     $consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();

    foreach($consulta as &$valor)
    {
        $sql = "
                    SELECT 
                        c.*,
                        cli.*,
                        f.idFuncionario,
                        f.*
                    FROM
                        chamada as c, cliente as cli, funcionario as f
                    WHERE
                        c.idCliente = '".$valor->idClienteChamada."'
                    AND
                        cli.idCliente = '".$valor->idClienteChamada."'
                    AND
                        c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario 
                    OR
                        c.idFuncionario = (NULL)
        ";  
         $valor->listaClientesView = $this->db->query($sql)->result();       
    }
```

Gostaria de listar TODAS as chamadas
mesmo que não tenha o idFuncionario dentro do chamada preenchido
Ele lista todas, de acordo com o cliente, porém, se não tiver um ID preenchido válido, ele não lista aquele registro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere seu SQL de

```
SELECT c.*,
       cli.*,
       f.idFuncionario,
       f.*
FROM chamada AS c,
     cliente AS cli,
     funcionario AS f
WHERE c.idCliente = '".$valor->idClienteChamada."'
  AND cli.idCliente = '".$valor->idClienteChamada."'
  AND c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario
  OR c.idFuncionario = (NULL)
```

Para

```
SELECT c.*,
       cli.*,
       f.idFuncionario,
       f.*
FROM chamada AS c
INNER JOIN cliente AS cli ON c.idCliente = cli.idCliente
LEFT JOIN funcionario AS f ON c.idFuncionario = f.idFuncionario
WHERE c.idCliente = '".$valor->idClienteChamada."'
```

Atenção ao `LEFT JOIN`, nessa situação ele vai trazer tudo o que estiver na tabela `chamada` mesmo que não existe `funcionario`.

Utilizar `JOIN` é muito mais prático e legível, se quiser saber mais tem essa ótima resposta aqui no ptSO.

#### [Diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/4087)

-

#### Problema da concatenação dos parâmetros

Tome cuidado! Isso abre brecha de segurança, uma delas é a execução de [`Sql Injection`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php). Uma alternativa no `PHP` com `CodeIgniter` é essa aqui:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?"; 

$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

#### Fonte: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

> The secondary benefit of using binds is that the values are automatically escaped, producing safer queries. You don't have to remember to manually escape data; the engine does it automatically for you.

Comment: Não consegui entender sobre a questão da segurança. Pode me dar mais detalhes? Assim não erro mais :))

Comment: @AndréBaill Atualizei a resposta falando sobre o problema da concatenação